# How can I reference this image so I can resize it

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to resize this table background image with javascript i also do not want it to repeat when it gets bigger

```
<table name="bgImgBlue" id="bgImgBlue" width="100%"  width="100%"width="100%"style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px; 
z-index:99;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" background="images/i_frame_bgnav.gif" HEIGHT="184">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Bakckground no repeat**

Take reference to image out of the property, and into the CSS (also make CSS external is better practise):

```
style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;background-image:url('images/i_frame_bgnav.gif');background-repeat:no-repeat;
```

The no repeat function will stop it repeating.  Alternative values for this are '`repeat-x`' and '`repeat-y`'.

**Better HTML**

Try and avoid tables, use div's instead.  These are easier to resize, and tables are pretty old school now.  Netherless, to resize your table's height:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    var myTable = document.getElementById("bgImgBlue");
    myTable.width = 300;
    myTable.height = 1000;
</script>
```

Comment: The script works but not the style. the image does not display

Comment: @Dave, sorry, add quotes around the image url (I've edited the answer)

Comment: I found the problem. the probem is my background image is amsll and it relys on repeat. when no repeat is on it shows behind another image and its too small to see. i only want it to repeat horizontily (from side to side) but not vertically(from top to bottom). when i put "repeat-x" it doesnt do the job because theyre not telling it not to repeat y. any ideas on how to to make it strech down instead of repeating down and only let it repeat to the side?

Answer (score 0):

First off, the modern thing is to use CSS for the whole thing:

```
table#bgImgBlue
 {
    width: 100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    z-index:99;
    height: 184px;
    background-image: url("images/i_frame_bgnav.gif");

  }
 ...
 <table id="bgImgBlue">
```

resizing a background image is possible only in CSS3, and not supported across all browsers yet. You may have to resize the original image on the server instead.

You can disable repeating the background image using

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Comment: I'd like to point out that, while this is the way it should be done on a web page to be browsed in a browser, Pekka's solution won't work in most mail clients. If this is something to be sent via email, it is actually better to have the style inlined (<table style="... )  since <style> tags are usually filtered out.

Comment: @Dave well, is it located in the right folder? Are you 100% sure? The `td`s have no background colour set that might overlap the image?

Comment: I found the problem. the probem is my background image is amsll and it relys on repeat. when no repeat is on it shows behind another image and its too small to see. i only want it to repeat horizontily (from side to side) but not vertically(from top to bottom). when i put "repeat-x" it doesnt do the job because theyre not telling it not to repeat y. any ideas on how to to make it strech down instead of repeating down and only let it repeat to the side?

Comment: @Dave nope, not in CSS2. You'll have to resize the actual image